# Opera IME support

Tags: javascript, events, localization, opera, ime

i am currently trying to get Input Mode Editor (IME) support working with a designMode enabled IFrame.

The problem here is with Opera it seems I don't get any useful notifications from the IME. It seems I get a single keydown with a keycode of 197 if the first time the IME is used - and nothing else ever again (No keycode 229 messages, no textinput event).

With all other browsers keydown events with an keycode of 229 seem to be common if there is something happening in the scope of the IME. And with some goodwill and combination of keyup with keycode 13 and textinput events it seems to be possible to detect the moment the sequence is done.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: this stuff isn't implemented in Opera, partly because it's not standardised anywhere how things should work. In TEXTAREA/INPUT you should be able to listen to "input" events but I don't know any usable events on a rich text editor IFRAME. Sorry about that.

Comment: is it still true? See [designMode](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/editing.html#designMode) in HTML5 specification.